# JQuery remove class from element if top = bottom of previous sibling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to remove a class from an element once the bottom of the previous sibling has scrolled to its top. The class I want to remove gives the element a fixed position, but I want to remove that fixed position once the user has scrolled to the point where the top of the fixed element is equal to the bottom of the previous element.

The problem is that all the .panel-grid elements are losing their .stuck-section class on scroll.

Here is what I've been trying with no luck so far:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $('.panel-grid.stuck-section').each(function(){
    var previous = $(this).prev('.panel-grid');
    if ($(this).offset().top <= previous.scrollTop() + previous.outerHeight()){
      $(this).removeClass('stuck-section');      
        }
  });
});
```

I've tried to fix it by changing

```
var previous = $(this).prev('.panel-grid').not('.stuck-section');
```

No luck, it still removes the class from all .panel-grid

Here's a pen: https://codepen.io/HennHoneyball/pen/devgOm

Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks!

```js
var panelCount = $('.panel-grid').length;
var num = panelCount;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.panel-grid').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-number', num--);
    var dataNum = $(this).attr('data-number');
  });
  $('.panel-grid:not(:first)').addClass('stuck-section');
  $('.panel-grid.stuck-section').each(function(){
    var dataNum = $(this).attr('data-number');
    $(this).css({'bottom': dataNum * 46 - 46, 'z-index': 100 - dataNum });
  });
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
  $('.panel-grid.stuck-section').each(function(){
    var curDataNumber = $(this).attr('data-number');
    var previous = $(this).prev('.panel-grid');
    if ($(this).offset().top <= previous.scrollTop() + previous.outerHeight()){
      $(this).removeClass('stuck-section');      
        }
  });
});
```

```css
.panel-layout{
  width:100%;
  padding-bottom: 300px;
}
.panel-grid{
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color:lightgray;
  min-height: 1000px;
}
.stuck-section{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px -3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.large-heading{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-layout">
  <div class="panel-grid">
    <p class="large-heading">Section 1</p>
  </div><!--panel-grid-->
  <div class="panel-grid">
    <p class="large-heading">Section 2</p>
  </div><!--panel-grid-->
  <div class="panel-grid">
    <p class="large-heading">Section 3</p>
  </div><!--panel-grid-->
  <div class="panel-grid">
    <p class="large-heading">Section 4</p>
  </div><!--pannel-row-->
  <div class="panel-grid">
    <p class="large-heading">Section 5</p>
  </div><!--panel-grid-->
</div><!--panel-layout-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something goes wrong in the calculation of scrollheight. I fiddled a bit and now it seems to be working.

changed this:

```
var scrollHeight = previous.scrollTop() + previous.outerHeight()
if (scrollHeight >= $(this).offset().top){
```

to this

```
var scrollHeight = previous.offset().top+ previous.outerHeight()
if (scrollHeight < $(this).offset().top){
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qrvbxj

Comment: Thank you very much Hans Dash, that works perfectly.